# C#: Multiline TextBox with TextBox.WordWrap Displaying Long Base64 String

Tags: c#, textbox, base64, word-wrap

I have a textbox to display a very long Base64 string.  The `TextBox.Multline = true` and `TextBox.WordWrap = true`.

The issue is caused by the auto-word-boundary detection of the TextBox itself.  The Base64 string has '+' as one of the 64 characters for Base64 encoding.  Therefore, the TextBox will wrap it up at the '+' character, which is not what I want (because the use might think there is a newline character around the '+' character).

I just want my Base64 string displayed in Mulitline-mode in TextBox, but no word boundary detection, that is, if the `TextBox.Width` can only contain 80 characters, then each line should have exact 80 characters except the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart wrap in too smart for your purposes.  Just keep `Multiline`, turn off `WordWrap` and wrap the text yourself:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SimpleWrap(string line, int length)
{
    var s = line;
    while (s.Length > length)
    {
        var result = s.Substring(0, length);
        s = s.Substring(length);
        yield return result;
    }
    yield return s;
}
```

**Update:**

An estimate of the number of characters that can fit in a `TextBox` using a fixed-width font is:

```
public int GetMaxChars(TextBox tb)
{
    using (var g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        return (int)Math.Floor(tb.Width / (g.MeasureString("0123456789", tb.Font).Width / 10));
    }
}
```

A variable-width font is harder but can be done with `MeasureCharacterRanges`.

Comment: How would you determine the length? Do not assume a fixed-width font.

Comment: It might be better to use `TextRenderer.MeasureText`.

Comment: The OP implied that he was using a fixed-width font.  If he is using a variable-width font, wrapping manually is a less attractive solution, but still possible.

Comment: @SLaks, can you make it more easy to understand or give me some sample code? Thanks. Happy New Year!

Comment: So how can you then convert IEnumerable string to string. I have lines in my textbox and only want to wrap some of them. So this is not working `textBox1.Text += SimpleWrap("my long text", GetMaxChars(textBox1));`

Comment: I started doing exactly all of this and got into a mess; eg, what if the user copies the text (with the line breaks)? What if the user edits the text (you need to manage the cursor). Etc. I just wish I could turn off so-called "SmartWrap".