# Multiline TextBox with custom word wrapping

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, ienumerable, word-wrap

I am beginning to program in .Net and C# and currently I am stuck. I have a very similar problem as the posting on this question at stackoverflow : [C#: Multiline TextBox with TextBox.WordWrap Displaying Long Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576457/c-multiline-textbox-with-textbox-wordwrap-displaying-long-base64-string).

The response to that question was this block of code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SimpleWrap(string line, int length) 
{ 
   var s = line; 
   while (s.Length > length) 
   { 
     var result = s.Substring(0, length); 
     s = s.Substring(length); 
     yield return result; 
   } 
   yield return s; 
}
```

I dont know how to make use of that piece of code. CAn someone please provide me with a code snippet that uses this particular method to write text that automatically also inserts a new line. 
My code currently looks like this:

```
var length = GetMaximumCharacters(txtBxResults);
var txtWrap = SimpleWrap(stringValue, length);
foreach (string s in txtWrap)
{
    txtBxResults.AppendText(s);
}
```

If I use AppendText method, it simple writes all the text in one single line which I do not want.
Any replies will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
KK

Comment: How is the textbox being used? I mean... Are you programatically filling it at once or appending text to it? Or is it for the user to type in?

Comment: @PedroC88 The textbox is populated programmatically. It fills in a combination of Chemical compounds with each element in a compound seperated by a hyphen and each compound seperated by a comma (Fe-Cr-Ni, Al-Ni-Co). What I want is the textbox should insert a new line at end of the line where there is a comma and not a hyphen. Also I dont need each compound in a new line, a new line should only begin when there is no more space left in the same line of the textbox. Hope I had explained myself clearly. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it right, you just need to insert the newline character as well. Try

```
foreach (string s in txtWrap)
{
  txtBxResults.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do what you suggest, then after each iteration of foreach, there is a new line which I do not want. I only want the textbox to insert a new line when the word cannot fit anymore in the textbox. Ideally the default wordwrap feature is good but since my words also contain the '-' (hyphen character), the textbox wordwrap breaks the word at the hyphen which I am not comfortable with. That's why I am using the code block which was suggested to a similar problem as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't give you the exact code right now (I'll come back and post it later) but in general, what you should do is identify the index of the next comma and, if characters on the current line + that index > length of the line then append a new line before that compound. If you do that in a bucle, when it's done it should be formatted correctly, also take into account the last compound won't have (I think) a comma at the end.