# How to display a Base64 string without treating + and / as word separators (which causes wonky formatting)

Tags: c#, wpf, base64

The default behavior for a `TextBox` with `WordWrapping` set to `Wrap` or `WrapWithOverflow` is to break the line on spaces, or what WPF considers space characters.

`+` and `/` is treated as such space characters, which causes a problem when handling Base64 strings. Instead of a nice continuous stream of characters, you get a choppy block with varying lengths.

Example of a properly formatted Base64 string:

```
QxZnrCFBGDNuBIlVz0393e++4LcGgU3QzCrCPfvZUg6RNGMSRKQE3gKaIApo+HRudBekn2JH3MLIlt/
2f9s4lLJ7w5rp65lKugK0a2FDaNO1U8njNLKrSlihSa7FDV8nYotY7TXahIh+WeRgknBhhC0MQSsSVF
//z3lCSKHqha2ijQnV63qe289AZNrOSrfnP8WAuMs0FQ0rWB27lzzmlNM3vgVni5mybmZc0e+EMYTBW
gjcac3hbnf7qZJd4kOSWdAGloyxf7QszUpl10QdpieY+T0zCioGVk+ObOEGVYsiyXcefpr4ENpUsJuC
fJYz3QNrxOgGX0+mAEA9IxPSJXi+Qg7M/iiMoOli31mOg9m4Wo7em5CjHGoneH1auuzHgYojwzmIZ97
a3iT+pH/1GHxmhMmF84rnGyWjpIaqMub9m13Pa7+gMPOvBLxspHjqMWAB8zUiQY3/O6gT5MJYL6w9AA
giJqy8xlTW1e/Oe3etuXImqT6w21nP0C8XjEsxV9QQLqNvyAuzRS3hTGyeMcAwZitPMYZtjSWvUlZ8p
DkJpH0bvkzTPfFnc2MRz47sMZ9v5iYg4SZOoqB9wHW1NqD016fvg3JzXSg56L0iXL6XwiG3DL0T6MJW
zRurVn18sT3DHPfm/a4s/In95vloK0bi5v1T/ini4O/lmLZXxwc=
```

Example of a poorly formatted Base64 string using a WPF `TextBox`, or `RichTextBox`;

```
QxZnrCFBGDNuBIlVz0393e++4LcGgU3QzCrCPfvZUg6RNGMSRKQE3gKaIApo
+HRudBekn2JH3MLIlt/2f9s4lLJ7w5rp65lKugK0a2FDaNO1U8njNLKrSlihSa7FDV8nYotY7TXahI
h+WeRgknBhhC0MQSsSVF//
z3lCSKHqha2ijQnV63qe289AZNrOSrfnP8WAuMs0FQ0rWB27lzzmlNM3vgVni5mybmZc0e
+EMYTBWgjcac3hbnf7qZJd4kOSWdAGloyxf7QszUpl10QdpieY+T0zCioGVk
+ObOEGVYsiyXcefpr4ENpUsJuCfJYz3QNrxOgGX0+mAEA9IxPSJXi+Qg7M/
iiMoOli31mOg9m4Wo7em5CjHGoneH1auuzHgYojwzmIZ97a3iT
+pH/1GHxmhMmF84rnGyWjpIaqMub9m13Pa7+gMPOvBLxspHjqMWAB8zUiQY3/
O6gT5MJYL6w9AAgiJqy8xlTW1e/
Oe3etuXImqT6w21nP0C8XjEsxV9QQLqNvyAuzRS3hTGyeMcAwZitPMYZtjSWvUlZ8pDkJpH0bvkzTP
fFnc2MRz47sMZ9v5iYg4SZOoqB9wHW1NqD016fvg3JzXSg56L0iXL6XwiG3DL0T6MJWzRurVn18sT3
DHPfm/a4s/In95vloK0bi5v1T/ini4O/lmLZXxwc=
```

The problem is the + and / characters. Can I force WPF to ignore those? Or is there a better way to edit Base64 strings?

edit: To clarify, this is a license key field, and it is used both to show the license key to the user, and to input a new license key (copy paste). If the license key looks wrong, the user might think something is wrong. Therefore, I cannot pre-format the string before binding to the TextBox.

Comment: please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576457/c-multiline-textbox-with-textbox-wordwrap-displaying-long-base64-string.

Comment: why don't you replace + and / to something you like by .ToString().Replace("+","");

Comment: Problem with both is that these are for displaying. This is a field the user can paste the Base64 string into. It's a license key. If it looks weird, the user might think something is wrong.

Comment: Removing + and / makes a Base64 string invalid. Not an option.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and am coming to really hate this SmartWrap "feature"! I'm thinking of creating a custom control inherited from `TextBox` and seeing if I can circumvent the errant wrapping that way. More when/if I manage to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I wanted to allow users to paste text in a base64 format so it could be converted into an image (long story), and I found that setting the textbox text to a base64 string would not corrupt it, but pasting into it would, as the OP mentions.

Looking at the inside of the clipboard, the text was correctly formatted, but during the pasting process it was getting corrupted/interpreted/converted. So, I decided to override the paste windows paste message for the TextBox, and lo-and-behold, it works!

The below code worked for me in WinForms. A similar solution would likely work in WPF.
Note: I had `Multiline` set to `true` and `WordWrap` set to `false`.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // handle paste message
        if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            // overwrite selected text with clipboard text
            this.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```